Generating battle maps for printing
I would like to acquire or generate flip-maps for StarFinder, preferably with the grid already incorporated.  I'm not trying to generate whole dungeons, just battle maps for scenarios.
Does someone know methods for quickly finding or creating battle maps to be printed out?

Tool recommendation questions are off topic.

@ThomasMarkov Well, I don't necessarily want a recommendations, I'll settle for any tool that can meet the requirements.  Does one even exist?  That's a little different than a recommendation.

Please read the linked meta discussion. This is a textbook example of an off topic recommendation question.

Hi Mark.  Following the recommendation in the meta that Thomas linked, I have attempted to "Make this process go easy by doing a quick edit instead of closing and all when the only difference between the question being OK and not OK is changing "I want a tool for this" to "I want a tool/technique/fix for this" in a whole question."  You are welcome to revert, but as you originally had it it will likely be closed.  By not asking directly for what you want you might actually get answers you find useful, and you might even find better answers than generative AI.

What's the trouble you run into when you try to find maps? Or, what have you tried? Is paying for a folio also an option?

@Kirt  I'm struggling to see how an answer would not end up not being a recommendation. There are plenty of forums and online groups where this sort of question can be posted.

@Senmurv My understanding of the meta posted by Thomas is that it is off topic to ask for a recommendation, but not off topic to answer with one.  The querent is instructed to state their problem as clearly as they can and if the expert solutions include tool recommendations, that is fine.  But the querent should not ask for tool recommendations specifically.  Consider the examples given of acceptable questions

@Kirt That makes sense. :) Thanks for taking the time to explain that. I got myself in a muddle.

@Kirt the only answer that does not skirt into a recommendation of a specific tool in this case might be suggesting the process to grid a map.

Gridding a Map
The problem you state is that you do not have a grid space. Any graphics program that supports layers can solve this in a couple of steps.
Among the many graphics programs that allow this process are Photoshop, GIMP, Clip Studio Paint, Paint Net, and many many more. The general progress to follow is basically 4 steps:

Find a map-like image you want to turn into a battle map.
Load the image into a graphics program as the lower layer.
Add a mostly transparent layer that holds just a grid.
Make sure this upper layer is properly scaled for printing.
Scale your lower layer till you are happy with the spacing.

The beauty of this process is, that if you save in a format that supports layers (.psd, .xcf .clip and others), then you can take this base file and just swap the lower layer to any other image file, scale it and you have a new battle map.
